# Change url of Canonical tag on sharepoint 2013 publishing site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, seo

I am doing SEO activities on my SharePoint 2013 Publishing site. For this I need to change my canonical URL on the publishing pages.

Can Any one suggest a way to do that?

Thanks in Advance